Snakemake run matrix of rules by piping parameter values from a previous rule
I can successfully do something like this,
numbers=[1,2,3]
words=["mum", "cat"]

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{n}_{w}.txt", n=numbers, w=words)

rule sim:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   output: 
      "{n}_{w}.txt"
   shell: 
      "echo 'Using {wildcards.n} and {wildcards.w}....' && touch {wildcards.n}_{wildcards.w}.txt"

This creates as expected 6 files.
Now I need to extend this to a more complex use case: the numbers and words lists get generated from a dataframe saved on .csv file by a previous rule. Then I want to use said parameter values (all combinations) to execute a jupyter notebook in a parametrized way with papermill.
The dataframe has a column for each parameter which might be repeated, so I would use this function
I think it would be something with a structure like this function to get the same lists of files as before
def get_values(infile):
   data = pd.read_csv(infile)
   return list(data.numbers.unique()), list(data.words.unique())

then the Snakefile might have the following structure,
rule all:
    input:
        expand("{n}_{w}.txt", n=numbers, w=words)

rule make_csv:
    output: dataframe="dataframe.csv"
    # not important how it is generated

# Here or in the next rule I am missing how to load the parameter values n and w

rule run_parametrized:
    input:
        notebook = "my_notebook.ipynb"
        (? parameters = rules.make_csv.output.dataframe)
    output:
        notebook = "result_{n}_{w}.ipynb"
    shell:
        "papermill {input.notebook} {output.notebook} -p number={n} -p word={w}"

Note that the "all" target rule here cannot work because I do not know in advance "numbers" and "words" because they should be somewhat output by a rule opening the CSV file and defining these lists globally.

This would call for Snakemake's checkpoint rule definition. A checkpoint tells snakemake to re-evaluate the DAG after its execution, allowing data-dependent conditional execution. For your example you could do the following:
rule all:
    input:
        aggregate_ipynbs

def aggregate_ipynbs(wildcards):
    checkpoint_output = checkpoints.make_csv.get(**wildcards).output[0] # tell snakemake to wait for checkpoint output
    data = pd.read_csv(checkpoint_output)
    ns, ws = list(data.numbers.unique()), list(data.words.unique())
    return expand("result_{n}_{w}.ipynb", n=ns, w=ws)

checkpoint make_csv:
    output: dataframe="dataframe.csv"
    # not important how it is generated

# Here or in the next rule I am missing how to load the parameter values n and w

rule run_parametrized:
    input:
        notebook = "my_notebook.ipynb"
        
    output:
        notebook = "result_{n}_{w}.ipynb"
    shell:
        "papermill {input.notebook} {output.notebook} -p number={n} -p word={w}"


